# MVC6 ViewComponents RenderInvoke() vs Invoke()

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I do not understand the purpose of IViewComponentHelper.RenderInvoke, as it returns void.

The Invoke method will render an html string in my view, which is what am I using always to render an MVC6 ViewComponent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `Invoke` and `RenderInvoke` is their return values and how their result gets to the final output.

With `@Component.Invoke(...)` you're able to execute a view component and render the value to the page. Or alternatively you can do:

```
@{
    HtmlString myHtmlString = Component.Invoke(...);
}
```

This can be useful because you get to inspect the output of the `Invoke` call prior to it being written to the result stream. In the case of `@Component.Invoke(...)` the output gets translated into an `HtmlString` and then lets the page write it to the result stream.

Now for `RenderInvoke`. `Component.RenderInvoke(...)` cannot be written with an `@` in front of it in the Razor page due to its return value (`void`). The purpose of this method is: I don't want any intermediary value (`HtmlString`) just write it directly to the result stream (`ViewContext.Writer`). Therefore you will always use `RenderInvoke` in a format similar to this:

```
@{
    Component.RenderInvoke(...);
}
```

To sum everything up. `Invoke` is used for convenience when you want to write `@Component.Invoke(...)` or is used to inspect the value by saving it to a variable. `RenderInvoke` does the least amount of work, doesn't create an `HtmlString` and writes directly to the final output; it's also convenient when you want to render `ViewComponents` in `@functions {...}` blocks:

```
@functions
{
    public void SomeUtility()
    {
        ...
        Component.RenderInvoke(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps!